# Proving the image set is $E^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Function $\mathbf g$ is $C^{(1)}$, and $\exists$ ${c\gt0}$  $\forall$  $s,t\in \mathbb R^n$ such that $|\mathbf{g(s)}-\mathbf{g}( t)|\geq c|\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{t}|$.

It can be proved that it it is injective(univalent) and it has $\det (D\mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{t}\right))\neq 0, \forall$ ${\mathbf{t}\in\mathbb{R}^n}$.

How do I prove that $\psi(\mathbf{t})=|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{t})|^2$ has a minimum, for any $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

This is an exercise from Fleming's book Function of Several Variables.

Comment: Do you mean $t \in \mathbb R^n $ (Reals)

Comment: yes. I'll edit it. Usually $E^n$ is $R^n$ with the euclidean inner product, I think. @Ram

Comment: Ohh, I am not aware of it. (as a non math major :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce yourself to proving that any such $|g|$ has a minimum, because then you can apply the result to $t \mapsto g(t) - x$. By rescaling $g$, you can assume $|g(s) - g(t)| \geq |s-t|$.

You have in particular $|g(s) - g(0)| \geq c|s|$ for every $s \in \mathbb{R}^n$. You also have $|g(s)| \geq |g(s) - g(0)| - |g(0)|$ (this is triangular inequality). Therefore $|g(s)| \geq |s| - |g(0)|$.

Now take the closed ball $B(0, 2|g(0)|)$ is compact, so $|g|$ has a minimum on this ball. The ball contains $0$, so this minimum is at most |g(0)|. And for $s$ outside this ball, $|s| \geq 2|g(0)|$, therefore $|g(s)| \geq |g(0)|$. Therefore the previous minimum was a global minimum.

Comment: Hi @nik, thanks for your answer. I still have some doubts.How do you prove from |g| having a minimum, that |g-x| has a minimum and that minimum is interior? The reason I think it is interior, is that I need to prove that $\mathbf{g}(\mathbb{R}^n) = \mathbb{R}^n$. And the exercise gives as a hint to prove that $\psi(\mathbf{t})=|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{t})|^2$ has a minimum. If that min is interior, then because $D\mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{t}\right))$ is non-singular, $(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{t_{\psi min}}))=\mathbf{0}$, which will imply that $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{g}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Comment: $d\psi (\mathbf{t})= (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{g(t_{\psi min})})^t \cdot D\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{t})$

Comment: Nevermind the thing about being interior... but I would still like to know how from |g| I prove that |g(t)-x| has a minimum. Thanks

Comment: @user105100: What I'm saying is that given a $g$ and a $x$, instead of proving that $|g(t) - x|$ has a minimum, then you can prove that $|h|$ has a minimum, where $h(t) = g(t) - x$. Then $h$ has exactly the same properties as $g$: it is $C^1$ and $|h(s) - h(t)| \geq |s-t|$.

Comment: One more thing, isn't the triangular inequality wrong? Shouldn't it be  $|g(s)|\le|g(s)−g(0)|+|g(0)|$ ?

Comment: No, because I say first $|g(s) - g(0)| \leq |g(s)| + |g(0)|$ and this implies what I wrote.

Comment: Many thanks @nik ;)